# Get foreground location with native code in Flutter without any pub packages

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-permissions

I want to get foreground location with native code(Kotlin) in Flutter without any pub packages.

So, how can I do it?
anyone can help?

Comment: Gotta explain... why no pub packages?  They're all generally liberally licensed and open source.

Comment: If I use location pub package to access location in foreground, when I try to upload it to play store they detect background location permission and reject my app even if i didn't use any background location permission in my manifest file. So I want to implement location feature with native code from scratch.

Comment: I suspect they'll figure it out anyway.  Doesn't matter if it's a pub package.  If it needs the permission, it'll eventually trigger their watchful eye.

Comment: But, I want to know how to implement this feature with native code in flutter.

Comment: read the pub source